# I am looking for a google-drive-api guide for java

Tags: java

I am developing an application where I have to use google-drive to give client access to the data present in drive. I am unable to find any particular guide or good pdf that helps me out understanding google-drive-api, is there anyone who can help me out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have checked their official documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java ?

Comment: Yes sir but it is not helping me much more.